# The title of my ChartJs on the chart is undefined, but I can't change it because my labels use a function: Object.keys(groupMedia)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The title of my ChartJs on the chart is undefined, but I can't change it because my labels use a function: Object.keys(groupMedia)

Could you please tell me what I should do to insert the name into the chartJS table instead of Undefined as in the image?

[Where is written undefined in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9dGo.png)

-> Where CHARTJS is defined

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('grafico').getContext('2d');
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: Object.keys(grupoMedia),
            datasets: [
                {
                //  text: 'Something2'
                    data: Object.values(grupoMedia)
                }
            ]
        }
    });
```

MY ALL JS CODE

```
const Chart = require('chart.js');
const Leaflet = require('leaflet');

let edtUrlDados = document.getElementById("urlDados");
let btnCarregarDados = document.querySelector("button");
let latestlabel;
let teste;
var myChart;
let valordados = new Array();
console.log(edtUrlDados.value);

function transformarDados(texto) {
    let linhas = texto.split("\n");
    let colunas = linhas[0].split("\t");
    let dados = new Array();

    for (let i = 1; i < linhas.length; i++) {
        let valores = linhas[i].split("\t");
        obj = {}
        for (let j = 0; j < colunas.length; j++) {
            obj[colunas[j]] = valores[j];
        }
        if (obj["Município"] == "PETROPOLIS") {
            dados.push(obj);            
        }
    }
    return dados;
}

function atualizarTabela(dados) {
    // colunas da tabela
    let thead_tr = document.querySelector("table > thead > tr");    
    for (let coluna in dados[0]) {
        let th = document.createElement('th');
        th.textContent = coluna;
        thead_tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    let tbody = document.querySelector("table > tbody");

    for (let obj of dados) {
        let tbody_tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (let nomePropriedade in obj) {
            let td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML = obj[nomePropriedade];
            tbody_tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        tbody.appendChild(tbody_tr);
    }
}

function atualizarGrafico(dados) {

    let grupo = {};
    for (let obj of dados) {
        let x = obj["Valor de Venda"];
        let y = obj["Data da Coleta"];
        if (grupo[y] === undefined) {
            grupo[y] = new Array();
        }
        grupo[y].push(x);
    }

    let grupoMedia = {};
    for (let nomePropriedade in grupo) {
        let soma = 0;
        for (let v of grupo[nomePropriedade]) {
            soma += parseInt(v);
        }       
        let quantidade = grupo[nomePropriedade].length;         
        grupoMedia[nomePropriedade] = soma / quantidade;
    }
    console.log(grupoMedia);
    console.log(Object.values(grupoMedia));

    

    const ctx = document.getElementById('grafico').getContext('2d');
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: Object.keys(grupoMedia),
            datasets: [
                {
                //  text: 'Something2'
                    data: Object.values(grupoMedia)
                }
            ]
        }
    });

}

var chkgasolina = document.getElementById("gasolina");
var chketanol = document.getElementById("etanol");
var absoluto = document.getElementById("absoluto");
var variacao = document.getElementById("variacao");

absoluto.checked = true;

function fillGrafico(){

    limparGrafico();
    if(chketanol.checked == true){
        
            let linhas = teste.split("\n");
            let colunas = linhas[0].split("\t");
            let dados2 = new Array();

            for (let i = 1; i < linhas.length; i++) {
                let valores = linhas[i].split("\t");
                obj = {}
                for (let j = 0; j < colunas.length; j++) {
                    obj[colunas[j]] = valores[j];
                }
                if (obj["Produto"] == "ETANOL") {
                    dados2.push(obj);           
                }
            }
            addDataE(dados2);
    
    }
    if(chkgasolina.checked == true){
        

            let linhas = teste.split("\n");
            let colunas = linhas[0].split("\t");
            let dados2 = new Array();

            for (let i = 1; i < linhas.length; i++) {
                let valores = linhas[i].split("\t");
                obj = {}
                for (let j = 0; j < colunas.length; j++) {
                    obj[colunas[j]] = valores[j];
                }
                if (obj["Produto"] == "GASOLINA") {
                    dados2.push(obj);           
                }
                if (obj["Produto"] == "GASOLINA ADITIVADA") {
                    dados2.push(obj);           
                }
            }
            addDataG(dados2);
    
    }

}

chkgasolina.onchange = function(){
        fillGrafico();
}

chketanol.onchange = function(){
        fillGrafico();
    }

absoluto.onchange = function(){
    if(absoluto.checked == true){
        fillGrafico();
    }
}



variacao.onchange = function(){
    if(variacao.checked == true){
        fillGrafico();
    }
}



function limparGrafico(){
    for(let i=0; i<myChart.data.datasets.length; i++){
            myChart.data.datasets.pop(-1);
    }
    myChart.data.datasets = [];
    myChart.update();
}


function removeDataG() {
    myChart.data.datasets.pop(-2);
    myChart.update();
    console.log("foi?");

}

function addDataG(dados2) {
    let grupo = {};
    
    for (let obj of dados2) {
        let x = obj["Valor de Venda"];
        let y = obj["Data da Coleta"];
        if (grupo[y] === undefined) {
            grupo[y] = new Array();
        }
        grupo[y].push(x);
        
    }
    

    let grupoMedia = {};
    for (let nomePropriedade in grupo) {
        let soma = 0;
        for (let v of grupo[nomePropriedade]) {
            soma += parseInt(v);
        }       
        let quantidade = grupo[nomePropriedade].length;         
        grupoMedia[nomePropriedade] = soma / quantidade;
    }

    if(variacao.checked==true){
        let grupov = Object.values(grupoMedia);
        let r = new Array();
                for (let i = 0; i<grupov.length;i++){
                    r.push(0);
                    if(i==0){
                        r[i]=0;}else{
                            r[i]=((grupov[i]/grupov[i-1])-1)*100;
                        }
                    }
        var newDataset = {
        labels: Object.keys(grupoMedia),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(165, 42, 42, 1)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(165, 42, 42, 1)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: r,
    }   

    }else{

       var newDataset = {
        labels: Object.keys(grupoMedia),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(165, 42, 42, 1)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(165, 42, 42, 1)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: Object.values(grupoMedia),
    }
    }
    myChart.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
    myChart.update();

}

function addDataE(dados2) {
    let grupo = {};
    for (let obj of dados2) {
        let x = obj["Valor de Venda"];
        let y = obj["Data da Coleta"];
        if (grupo[y] === undefined) {
            grupo[y] = new Array();
        }
        grupo[y].push(x);
    }

    let grupoMedia = {};
    for (let nomePropriedade in grupo) {
        let soma = 0;
        for (let v of grupo[nomePropriedade]) {
            soma += parseInt(v);
        }       
        let quantidade = grupo[nomePropriedade].length;         
        grupoMedia[nomePropriedade] = soma / quantidade;
    }

    if(variacao.checked==true){
        let grupov = Object.values(grupoMedia);
        let r2 = new Array();
                for (let i = 0; i<grupov.length;i++){
                    r2.push(0);
                    if(i==0){
                        r2[i]=0;}else{
                            r2[i]=((grupov[i]/grupov[i-1])-1)*100;
                        }
                    }
        var dataset1 = {
        labels: Object.keys(grupoMedia),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba( 30, 144, 255, 1 )',
        borderColor: 'rgba( 30, 144, 255, 1 )',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: r2,
        
    }   

    }else{

       var dataset1 = {
        labels: Object.keys(grupoMedia),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba( 30, 144, 255, 1 )',
        borderColor: 'rgba( 30, 144, 255, 1 )',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: Object.values(grupoMedia),
    }
    }
    myChart.data.datasets.push(dataset1);
    console.log("chamado");
    myChart.update();
}

function carregarDados() {
    console.log("fui clicado!");
    fetch(edtUrlDados.value)
        .then(r => r.text())
        .then(t => {
            teste = t;
            console.log(teste);
            let dados = transformarDados(t);
            atualizarTabela(dados);
            atualizarGrafico(dados);
            limparGrafico();
            // atualizar o mapa
            atualizarMapa(dados);
        });
}

function atualizarMapa(dados) {
    var map = Leaflet.map('map').setView([-22.5075743, -43.1785356], 13);

    Leaflet.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

    L.marker([-22.5075743, -43.1785356]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();
}

btnCarregarDados.addEventListener("click", carregarDados);
```

My HTML CODE

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
            integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
            crossorigin=""/>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Preços dos Combistíveis</h1>

        <h2>Fonte dos dados</h2>
        <p>         
            <input type="text" id="urlDados" value="http://pav.elfcorreia.com.br/combustiveis.csv">
            <button>Verificar e carregar</button>
        </p>

        <h2>Dados</h2>
        <!-- <div style="border: solid 1pt red; height: 150px; overflow: scroll;"> -->
            <table style="display: block; border: solid 1pt black; height: 250px; overflow: scroll;">
                <thead><tr></tr></thead>        
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        <!-- </div> -->


        //JS CHART RECOMMENDATION STARTS HERE IN ID
        <h2>Serie Histórica dos Preços</h2>

        <p>Combustível: 
            <input type="checkbox" id="gasolina" value="gasolina">
            <label>gasolina</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="etanol">
            <label>etanol</label>
        </p>

        <p>Valores: 
            <input type="radio" name="valores" id="absoluto">
            <label>preço absoluto</label>
            <input type="radio" name="valores" id="variacao">
            <label>variação em %</label>
        </p>

        <!-- <div style="width: 100%; height: 150px; border: solid 1pt black;"></div> -->
        <div style="border: solid 1pt black;">
            <canvas id="grafico" style="width: 100%; height: 250px;"></canvas>
        </div>

        <h2>Visualização no Mapa</h2>

        <p>
            data: 
            <select>
                <option>01/05/2021</option>
            </select>
            municipios: 
            <select>
                <option>Petrópolis</option>
            </select>
        </p>

        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 350px; border: solid 1pt black;"></div>

        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined because you never set it. You have to configure the `label` option in the dataset and not `labels`, the dataset also does not have a labels option if I remember correctly.

```js
new Chart('canvasId', {
  type: 'line'
  data: {
    labels: ['a','b'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [4,7],
      label: 'text that appears in the legend that is undefined right now'
    }]
  },
  options: {}
})
```

Comment: Could you explain better how to do this?

Comment: It's not working yet :/

My labels it's not 'a' 'b', so i mean is diferent, my labels is: Object.keys(grupoMedia), a function. When I put labet: 'name' doesn't work... And my Data is data: Object.values(grupoMedia).

Comment: I have two lines in the graphics, one for gasoline and onother for Alcohol.

Comment: Yeah I know but its about that label field in your dataset so your labels or data doesnt matter how you define that, in each dataset you have a `label` field which isn't the labels on the x axis but just an identifier on what that dataset is about

Comment: When I put `label` field, nothing happens. I think that's because it has two datasets, one for gasoline and one for alcohol.

Comment: then you must be placing it at the wrong place because each dataset can have a label field with text, because if you dont have it it will show undefined

Comment: I still can't, can you help me using my code as an example?